# Select Div Tag: Options Longer than screen! How to auto-wrap text?

Tags: html, css

I have the following html code:

```
<select name="questionSelectedID" style="width: auto; position: relative; text-overflow: ellipsis;">
       //for loop generating options
 </select>
```

The result I get using this CSS is:

[image: Resulting select div]

My options are very long and they are cut off by the width of my screen. I though the css for this tag (see code snippet) should work. What code can wrap the options so they stay within the size of the window?

Note: my  tags do not have any css to them.

Comment: You really should cionsider not using a `select` element here. A list of `<input type="radio">` with `<label>`s containing the text would be much more appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

variation on Alex Yepes answer. What ended up working was using styling that referenced the select tag:

```
.container select {

}
```

Simply using the the container div does not affect the width of the select (but it does affect the rest of the content within the div).

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this in your **js**

```
    let el = document.querySelectorAll('option')
    el.forEach(x => {
      if (x.textContent.length > 25) // change the 25 according to your need
        x.textContent = x.textContent.substring(0, 25) + '...';
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start would be to learn the box model (https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp). You need to wrap your elements inside a parent element, give that element a class, then give that class the properties to define how wide your container will be. Here is a small example: html

```
<div class=”container”>
    <select>
        //for loop generating options
    </select>
</div>
```

Css

```
.container {
    width: 100%; //takes the whole width of the element from left to right
    display: block; //occupies the whole element
}
```

Everything inside your div will not go beyond the width specified in your css

Comment: Are you sure this applies for the select tag? Wrapping the the select with the div with the style I want doesn't seem to apply to the div.

Comment: Yes, once you give the property of width: 100% to your parent container, (div in my example), nothing should go beyond the container boundaries. If for some reason the content inside that div is wider then the div container, then you can specify how you want to manage the overflow: hidden, or scroll, or auto